# Remove minus sign from the the negative values of the secondary x-axis

Tags: d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

The screenshot shows the values along with the minus sign along the secondary x-axis. I want to get rid of it. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

[image: Multibar-Horizontal Chart]

Below is the code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['nvd3']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {


    $scope.options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'multiBarHorizontalChart',
            height: 500,
            x: function(d){return d.label;},
            y: function(d){return d.value;},
            //yErr: function(d){ return [-Math.abs(d.value * Math.random() * 0.3), Math.abs(d.value * Math.random() * 0.3)] },
            showControls: true,
            showValues: true,
            duration: 500,
            stacked: true,
            xAxis: {
                showMaxMin: false
            },
            yAxis: {
                axisLabel: 'Values',
                tickFormat: function(d){
                    return d3.format(',f')(d);

                }
            }
        }

    };
```

Comment: did you check the value on y : function  console the d.value; and check the negative value inside

Comment: I checked. It didn't log any value.

Comment: silent  this line    //return d.value; and insert console.log(d.value);

Comment: The chart is not displayed. The page went blank.

Comment: yes now check the console what is print

Comment: why don't you filter out negative value label from your dataset. That will solve your problem

Comment: I just want to get rid of the minus sign and not the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adjust the `tickFormat` of your `yAxis`:

```
yAxis: {
    axisLabel: 'Values',
    tickFormat: function(d){
        return d3.format(',f')(Math.abs(d));   // Use Math.abs() to get the absolute value
    }
}
```

This will pass the absolute tick value to the formatter rendering all values without the minus sign.